# "winter-gardening" tag vs "wintering"

Tags: discussion, tags

Is [winter-gardening](/questions/tagged/winter-gardening) meant to refer to active gardening only? Should there be another tag, perhaps [wintering](/questions/tagged/wintering), to refer to questions about the care of plants that are dormant during the winter?

Comment: Related: http://meta.gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/235/fall-winter-gardening-tag

Comment: That post is related, and I did see it, but it also seems to be about _active_ gardening as opposed to managing/caring for a dormant plant to make sure it survives the winter. I'm just wondering whether the [meta-tag:winter-gardening] tag is meant to encompass both usages, and whether that is intuitive for users (it wasn't for me).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tag that you're looking for is [over-wintering](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/over-wintering), and that would deal with the care of plants that are dormant during winter. [winter-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-gardening) is broader, in the sense that it could be anything you do to your plant/garden during the winter. For your question on roses, it would be appropriate to tag it with both tags, as bstpierre has done.

On the other hand, in some places (like San Diego for instance), although we have a "winter" season, stuff still grows (albeit very slowly) and there is no need for over-wintering any thing. So if I were growing lettuce/kale/spinach from fall through spring, I'd probably tag it with the appropriate vegetable tags and [winter-gardening](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/winter-gardening).

Hope that made it clear :)

Comment: [tag:over-wintering] makes sense as the parent name, but I think [tag:wintering] should be set up as a synonym of [tag:over-wintering] - people are probably more likely to start to type "wint" when they mean this.  Agree about [tag:winter-gardening] - to me this is more active (eg. planting plants, preparing beds) rather than making sure plants survive winter okay.

Comment: @winwaed certainly. Please suggest the synonym [here](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/tags/over-wintering/synonyms).

Comment: I need a 5 score on a tag in order to suggest a synonym.

Comment: hmmm.. damn those rules. I'll get Mike to suggest it then.

Comment: Yes that is why I keep asking/suggesting synonyms and I think I've only actually created one or perhaps two.

Comment: well, those rules were designed for [so] and don't really work here. I'll try and lobby to have that changed.

Comment: I think they are intended for a mature site, where you might want to limit synonyms to people who have demonstrated some knowledge. Here the site is so young, there are few with sufficient score on each tag.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. As a novice gardener I did not understand what over-wintering referred to. I do think adding "wintering" as a synonym makes sense.

Comment: @Amanda_A It has been added as a synonym.

Comment: @winwaed For future reference, if you enter "wint", you'll see "over-wintering" in the suggestions whether or not there is a synonym. The tag suggestion doesn't base it only at the start of the word.